# Limit of a bounded function is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I am working on proving the following proposition:

If $a \leq f(x) \leq b$ and $\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = L$ then $a \leq L \leq b$.

Starting out with the epsilon-delta definition of a limit, we quickly find that whenever $|x-c| < \delta$,
$$L - \epsilon < f(x) < L + \epsilon$$
I am getting stuck here. How do I combine this inequality with the presupposition that $a \leq f(x) \leq b$? It doesn't seem like it's possible to isolate $L$, $a$, and $b$.

Comment: Assume $L\gt b$ and derive a contradiction by choosing $\epsilon=\frac12(L-b).$ Also you can repeat essentially same argument for the case $L\lt a.$

Comment: I'm not sure I follow:
$|f(x) - L| < \frac{L-b}{2} \implies \frac{b-L}{2} < f(x) - L< \frac{L-b}{2} \implies b-L < 2f(x) - 2L < L-b \implies b+L < 2f(x) < 3L-b$. When you cut out the $2f(x)$, we find $b+L < 3L - b \implies 2b < 2L$ which is not a contradiction.

Comment: @chrisduds it is a contradiction because we get $b<\frac{b+L}2<f(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume this is false, so $L>b$ or $L<a$, in this case we have:

Forall $\epsilon>0$ exists $\delta>0$ such that $|x-c|<\delta$ implies that $L-\epsilon<f(x)<L+\epsilon$

If $L>b$ choose $\epsilon=L+b+1$ to get $b+1<f(x)<2L+b+1$, this is contradiction.

If $L<a$ choose $\epsilon=-L+a-1$ to get $-2L+a-1<f(x)<a-1$, another contradiction.

Hence $a\le L\le b$

Comment: Thanks, in the future for these kinds of proofs I'll try and remember I can choose $\epsilon$ to be anything.

Comment: @chrisduds: Not anything, but a positive number created using related inequalities.